Can I "i++" inside a function if "int i = 0" is written outside of it?
I'm working on Problem Set 1 2024, to which I wrote a functioning file which answers the problem.
Nonetheless, I decided to try to "clean" it a little bit and make it more readable.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void coin(int value, int n);

int main(void)
{

    // prompt user for a change value
    int change = get_int("Change owed: ");

    // force prompt for positive integer
    while (change <= 0)
    {
        change = get_int("Change owed: ");
    }

    int i = 0;
    //repeat below line for each coin
    coin(change, 25);
    
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

//returns number of coins for the change value
void coin(int value, int n)
{
    while(value / n >= 1)
    {
        value = value - n;
        i++;
    }
}

Here lies the problem:
"i" is defined in main, outside of coin(), so when I try compiling, I get the unidentified variable error, in my coin() function.
How can I define int i = 0 so that it's used in my coin() function and incremented correctly?
I tried defining int i = 0 inside of coin(), but then my printf("&s\n") in main doesn't recognize i, as it's inside of coin().
I tried defining int i = 0 as a global variable (despite multiple google searches righftfully telling me it was a mistake), and even though it compiles, it is an incorrect solution to the problem.
I tried learning whether some sort of variable definition prototype exists, to no avail.
Now, I've ran out of ideas and don't know if what I want is possible anymore.
I know I can submit the working code and be done with it, but I'm trying to be thorough and learn as much as possible in each problem set, exploring all options and trying to write good code that looks good too.

You cannot modify i from main from coin. One way to solve it is to pass a pointer to i to coin and modify it via the pointer.

I haven't learned about pointers yet. I'll study some more and try coming up with the solution. If I figure out the problem, should I delete this post, or should I publish my solution in the answers?

It seems like it'd make more sense to return the count, rather than trying to directly modify the caller's variables.

What does CS50 say about variable scope and lifetime?

I think the solution suggested above by @user2357112 is the correct one here. Although as I wrote passing a pointer will allow to change i in main, in this case return a value is a better solution.

@user2357112 I thought that's what I was trying to do with printf on main(). I don't think I understand how to do what you're suggesting. I'm really new to this.

@Someprogrammerdude regarding scope I know already what wohlstad mentioned, although apparently you can "bypass" this with pointers? I don't know about this lifetime concept in C.

The way to do that is to return the number from the function:
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int coin(int value, int n);

int main(void)
{

    // prompt user for a change value
    int change = get_int("Change owed: ");

    // force prompt for positive integer
    while (change <= 0)
    {
        change = get_int("Change owed: ");
    }

    //repeat below line for each coin
    int i = coin(change, 25);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

//returns number of coins for the change value
int coin(int value, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(value / n >= 1)
    {
        value = value - n;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}


Thank you for helping!
I tried implementing your changes and I get error on line 18: initializing 'int' with an expression of incompatible type 'void': int i = coin(change, 25). Additionally, how would I get this to work if I have 4 coins (25, 10, 5 and 1)?

@girurerumu: Sounds like you forgot to change the return type of coin.

@user2357112 you're right. It compiles! but now I'm trying to figure out how to more iterations of coin() to i.

@girurerumu since this is a different issue, please post a new question. Regarding this one, please see: What should I do when someone answers my question?.


How can I define int i = 0 so that it's used in my coin() function and incremented correctly?

The solution below is working, and alternative to the proposed solution by Aykhan Hagverdili.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void coin(int value, int n);

int i = 0;

int main(void)
{

    // prompt user for a change value
    int change = get_int("Change owed: ");

    // force prompt for positive integer
    while (change <= 0)
    {
        change = get_int("Change owed: ");
    }

    //repeat below line for each coin
    coin(change, 25);
    
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

//returns number of coins for the change value
void coin(int value, int n)
{
    while(value / n >= 1)
    {
        value = value - n;
        i++;
    }
}

Sorry, I cannot test your example code as I have no access to <cs50.h> code.  I needed to provide a function get_int() to be able to test it.  You need to follow the guidelines of How to create a minimal, reproducible example to post your questions.

CS50 is a well-known library from Harvard University, used for beginner C courses.

I know, but as I'm not a harvard student, it is difficult to me to do the  proper testing of the proposed code without changing the source itself.  I do it happily for a newcomer, but I also recommend him to post [minimal, reproducible example].  While the example is minimal, and complete, it is not easily reproducible.  This sample is easy enough to allow me to modify it in the trust that I will not introduce/eliminate any error esential to answer the question, only because the sample code is not reproducible.  I'm not a Harvard Student and I assume Harvard has its...

... own system to make students to avoid asking their homework questions in StackOverflow.

Thank you Luis. I ended up abandoning this approach altogether and created an array instead, which I then integrated into my loop function. It's much simpler than what I was trying to do. I just had to study a bit about arrays (which are actually the following lesson's topic).

This means that i wont get a vote?  Ok, don’t worry. You are welcome equally.
